# How to addTraining phrases & train the Dialogflow intent to better match entities using Dialogflow V2 beta 1 API in java?

Tags: java, json, dialogflow-es

Goal:- I want to insert training phrases in dialogfow from dialogflow v2 Beta API in Java.

---

**for ex:** 
Training phrases:- I want *pizza*.
please order *pizza*

Action and parameters :
PARAMETER NAME: Topping,
ENTITY :@Topping,
VALUE: $Topping

My current code:-

```
List<TrainingPhrase> trainingPhrases = new ArrayList<>();
      for (String trainingPhrase : trainingPhrasesParts) {
          for (String parm : parameters) {
              for (String enti : entity_type) {
        trainingPhrases.add(
            TrainingPhrase.newBuilder().addParts(
                    Part.newBuilder().setText(trainingPhrase).setText(response_value).setAlias(parm).setEntityType(enti).build())
                .build());   
          }}
      }

  // Build the intent
      Intent intent = Intent.newBuilder()
          .setDisplayName(displayName)
          .addMessages(message)
          .addAllTrainingPhrases(*trainingPhrases*)
          .build();
```

this results me JSON in .addAllTrainingPhrases(*trainingPhrases*):

```js
[parts {
  text: " pizza"
  entity_type: "@Topping"
  alias: "topping"
}
]
```

while Required json to training phrases:-

```js
"parts": [
        {
          "text": "I want "
        },
        {
          "text": "pizza",
          "entityType": "Topping",
          "alias": "topping"
        }
      ]
```